# heroku push installs OpenJDK 1.6 instead of OpenJDK 1.8

Tags: grails, heroku, intellij-idea, heroku-toolbelt

- I am using IntelliJ 14 with heroku plugin and connection to heroku is successfully. Yet I can't commit changes to heroku .
- My application uses grails 2.5 & Java 8.
- It seems like heroku is installing OpenJDK 1.6 instead of OpenJDK 1.8.

Is there any way to force heroku to install OpenJDK 1.8?

trace :

```
 12:57:01.488: cd C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\MyWebApp
    12:57:01.488: git -c core.quotepath=false log refs/heads/master --not --remotes=heroku --max-count=1000 --pretty=format:%x01%H%x02%ct%x02%an%x02%at%x02%ae%x02%cn%x02%ce%x02%P%x02%s%x02%b%x02%B%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 -M --name-status -c --
    12:59:24.248: cd C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\MyWebApp
    12:59:24.248: git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain heroku refs/heads/master:master --set-upstream
    Fetching repository, done.
    Counting objects: 1633, done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (1462/1462), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (1633/1633), 53.48 MiB | 188.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 1633 (delta 703), reused 0 (delta 0)
    -----> Grails app detected
    -----> Grails 2.5.0 app detected
           WARNING: The Grails buildpack is currently in Beta.
    -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
    -----> Executing ./grailsw -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=/app/tmp/cache compile --non-interactive
           Downloading http://dist.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/GRAILS/grails-2.5.0.zip to /app/.grails/wrapper/grails-2.5.0-download.zip
           .................................................................................
           Extracting /app/.grails/wrapper/grails-2.5.0-download.zip to /app/.grails/wrapper/2.5.0
    Apr 11, 2015 10:15:38 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
    WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
           | Loading Grails 2.5.0
           | Configuring classpath
           | Downloading: org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
           | Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.5/slf4j-parent-1.7.5.pom
           | Downloading: jline/jline/2.12/jline-2.12.pom
           | Downloading: org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.4/ant-1.8.4.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.4/ant-parent-1.8.4.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.8.4/ant-launcher-1.8.4.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-trax/1.7.1/ant-trax-1.7.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.7.1/ant-parent-1.7.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-junit/1.8.4/ant-junit-1.8.4.pom
           | Downloading: net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.0.0/jna-4.0.0.pom
           | Downloading: org/codehaus/gant/gant_groovy1.8/1.9.6/gant_groovy1.8-1.9.6.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.2/ant-1.8.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.2/ant-parent-1.8.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.8.2/ant-launcher-1.8.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.pom
           | Downloading: org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
           | Downloading: org/fusesource/jansi/jansi-project/1.11/jansi-project-1.11.pom
           | Downloading: org/fusesource/fusesource-pom/1.8/fusesource-pom-1.8.pom
           | Downloading: org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.1/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.6.1/slf4j-parent-1.6.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/commons/commons-parent/17/commons-parent-17.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55.2/tomcat-7.0.55.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/7.0.55/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.55.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.55.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.55.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.55.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-websocket-7.0.55.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.55.pom
           | Downloading: org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.55.2/tomcat-7.0.55.2.zip
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ant/7.0.55/tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.55.jar
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.55.jar
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.55.jar
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.55.jar
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-websocket-7.0.55.jar
           | Downloading: org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.jar
           | Downloading: org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.55/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.55.jar
           | Downloading: net/java/jvnet-parent/1/jvnet-parent-1.pom
           | Downloading: org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.1.5.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.pom
           | Downloading: opensymphony/sitemesh/2.4/sitemesh-2.4.pom
           | Downloading: org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.1.5.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.5/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-core/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.3.1/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.pom
           | Downloading: javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.pom
           | Downloading: commons-validator/commons-validator/1.4.0/commons-validator-1.4.0.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/commons/commons-parent/23/commons-parent-23.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom
           | Downloading: commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/commons/commons-parent/32/commons-parent-32.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
           | Downloading: commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/commons/commons-parent/24/commons-parent-24.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-gorm-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-simple/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-simple-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/commons/commons-parent/22/commons-parent-22.pom
           | Downloading: asm/asm-parent/3.3.1/asm-parent-3.3.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/objenesis/objenesis/1.4/objenesis-1.4.pom
           | Downloading: org/objenesis/objenesis-parent/1.4/objenesis-parent-1.4.pom
           | Downloading: org/hamcrest/hamcrest-parent/1.3/hamcrest-parent-1.3.pom
           | Downloading: cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-test-support/1.0.2-grails-2.4/grails-datastore-test-support-1.0.2-grails-2.4.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/scaffolding/2.1.2/scaffolding-2.1.2.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/cache/1.1.8/cache-1.1.8.pom
           | Downloading: org/javassist/javassist/3.17.1-GA/javassist-3.17.1-GA.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/webxml/1.4.1/webxml-1.4.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/asset-pipeline/2.1.5/asset-pipeline-2.1.5.pom
           | Downloading: org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/rhino-1.7R4.pom
           | Downloading: com/bertramlabs/plugins/asset-pipeline-core/2.1.1/asset-pipeline-core-2.1.1.pom
           | Downloading: com/google/javascript/closure-compiler/v20141023/closure-compiler-v20141023.pom
           | Downloading: com/google/javascript/closure-compiler-parent/v20141023/closure-compiler-parent-v20141023.pom
           | Downloading: org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/9/oss-parent-9.pom
           | Downloading: com/google/javascript/closure-compiler-externs/v20141023/closure-compiler-externs-v20141023.pom
           | Downloading: args4j/args4j/2.0.26/args4j-2.0.26.pom
           | Downloading: args4j/args4j-site/2.0.26/args4j-site-2.0.26.pom
           | Downloading: org/kohsuke/pom/6/pom-6.pom
           | Downloading: com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom
           | Downloading: com/google/guava/guava-parent/18.0/guava-parent-18.0.pom
           | Downloading: com/google/google/1/google-1.pom
           | Downloading: commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/hibernate4/4.3.8.1/hibernate4-4.3.8.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-validator-parent/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-parent-5.1.3.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.0.2.Final/arquillian-bom-1.0.2.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.0.1/shrinkwrap-bom-1.0.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom/1.0.0-beta-7/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-1.0.0-beta-7.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-3/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-3.pom
           | Downloading: javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/jboss-parent/9/jboss-parent-9.pom
           | Downloading: com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.3.8.Final/hibernate-ehcache-4.3.8.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/jboss-parent/10/jboss-parent-10.pom
           | Downloading: dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.pom
           | Downloading: xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.pom
           | Downloading: antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/jboss-parent/5/jboss-parent-5.pom
           | Downloading: net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/2.9.0/ehcache-2.9.0.pom
           | Downloading: net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-root/2.9.0/ehcache-root-2.9.0.pom
           | Downloading: net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-parent/2.16/ehcache-parent-2.16.pom
           | Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.pom
           | Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.7/slf4j-parent-1.7.7.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/jboss-parent/7/jboss-parent-7.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-tools-parent/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-tools-parent-1.2.0.Beta1.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-validator-parent/5.0.3.Final/hibernate-validator-parent-5.0.3.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.1.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.pom
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.4.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/springframework/spring-orm/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/database-migration/1.4.0/database-migration-1.4.0.pom
           | Downloading: org/liquibase/liquibase-core/2.0.5/liquibase-core-2.0.5.pom
           | Downloading: org/liquibase/liquibase-parent/2.0.5/liquibase-parent-2.0.5.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.pom
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/scaffolding/2.1.2/scaffolding-2.1.2.zip
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/cache/1.1.8/cache-1.1.8.zip
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/asset-pipeline/2.1.5/asset-pipeline-2.1.5.zip
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/webxml/1.4.1/webxml-1.4.1.zip
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/hibernate4/4.3.8.1/hibernate4-4.3.8.1.zip
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/database-migration/1.4.0/database-migration-1.4.0.zip
           | Downloading: org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.zip
           | Downloading: org/javassist/javassist/3.17.1-GA/javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar
           | Downloading: cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-test-support/1.0.2-grails-2.4/grails-datastore-test-support-1.0.2-grails-2.4.jar
           | Downloading: com/bertramlabs/plugins/asset-pipeline-core/2.1.1/asset-pipeline-core-2.1.1.jar
           | Downloading: org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/rhino-1.7R4.jar
           | Downloading: com/google/javascript/closure-compiler/v20141023/closure-compiler-v20141023.jar
           | Downloading: com/google/javascript/closure-compiler-externs/v20141023/closure-compiler-externs-v20141023.jar
           | Downloading: args4j/args4j/2.0.26/args4j-2.0.26.jar
           | Downloading: com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
           | Downloading: commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
           | Downloading: javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
           | Downloading: com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.3.8.Final/hibernate-ehcache-4.3.8.Final.jar
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.8.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar
           | Downloading: org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
           | Downloading: antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
           | Downloading: org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
           | Downloading: net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/2.9.0/ehcache-2.9.0.jar
           | Downloading: org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
           | Downloading: org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.4.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
           | Downloading: org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
           | Downloading: dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
           | Downloading: org/springframework/spring-orm/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
           | Downloading: org/grails/grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support/3.1.4.RELEASE/grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
           | Downloading: org/liquibase/liquibase-core/2.0.5/liquibase-core-2.0.5.jar
           | Downloading: org/liquibase/liquibase-core/2.0.5/liquibase-core-2.0.5.jar.
           | Environment set to development
           | Environment set to development.
           | Environment set to development..
           | Environment set to development...
           | Environment set to development....
           | Environment set to development.....
    -----> Executing ./grailsw -plain-output -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=/app/tmp/cache war --non-interactive
    Apr 11, 2015 10:16:18 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
    WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
           |Loading Grails 2.5.0
           |Configuring classpath
           .
           |Environment set to production
           .................................
           |Packaging Grails application
           .....................................
           |Compiling 8 GSP files for package [MyWebApp]
           ..
           |Compiling 4 GSP files for package [databaseMigration]
           ..
           |Building WAR file
           .............................................................
           |Precompiling Assets!
           .Error 
           |
           Error executing script War: java/nio/file/FileSystems (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
     !     Failed to build app
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Grails app
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:MyWebApp.git'
    To git@heroku.com:MyWebApp.git
    !   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)
```

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.8
grails.project.source.level = 1.8
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55.2" // or ":tomcat:8.0.20"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"
        //compile ":nimble:0.7"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like it fails with building the assets.  does a `grails war` run locally on your box?  also for the jdk: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk

Comment: grails war runs successfully local.

Comment: @shaydel can you show us your BuildConfig.groovy file?

Comment: added it , i now get a new error ->        Invalid commandline usage for javac.
       javac: invalid source release: 1.8

Comment: Remote,i got it while trying to push with git via intellij heroku configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is way to install OpenJDK 1.8.

For that you need to create a file `system.properties` in root of the project and add following line

`java.runtime.version=1.8`

Then add and commit the file in git and push to heruko.

Console log after adding the `system.properties` file :

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Grails app detected
remote: -----> Grails 2.4.4 app detected
remote:        WARNING: The Grails buildpack is currently in Beta.
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8...done
```

Console log before adding the `system.properties` file :

```
remote: -----> Grails app detected
remote: -----> Grails 2.4.4 app detected
remote:        WARNING: The Grails buildpack is currently in Beta.
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
.............
remote:        | Installed plugin tomcat-7.0.55.....
remote:        | Compiling 10 source files
remote:   [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
remote:   [groovyc] Invalid commandline usage for javac.
remote:   [groovyc] javac: invalid source release: 1.8
remote:   [groovyc] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Reference : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-grails#optional-choose-a-jdk

Comment: also i created new project and tried pushing again now i get new errors - Error executing script War: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/scaffolding/GrailsTemplateGenerator : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace) . I used to have JDK 7+8 installed at the same time ,but removed 7, and clear ENV VARS respectively